# Bamboo Deployment Project doesn't start just gets queued

Tags: deployment, bamboo

I am trying to deploy a Bamboo Deployment Project. On manual deploy the project only gets queued and never starts.

I have three Tasks:

1. Clean working directory
2. Dowload war artifact
3. Deploy to server with a script

I also tried my deployment project it with one simple echo script task for debugging purposes. This also never executes and no logs appear.

Can anyone help or knows a possible reason for this problem?

Comment: This can be caused by no agents having capabilities that meet the requirements of the deployment task.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen in two cases

1. The agent with which you are trying to build may not have the necessary capabilities.
2. The agent might be dedicated to some other projects.

The solution is to add necessary capabilities in the first case or to dedicate the agent to deployment project also.

Comment: the link is dead.
These reasons are not the 'only' reasons this can happen.